# AttachAll exception: type arguments for method cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly

Tags: linq-to-sql

**Scenario**:
Trying to call the `.AttachAll` method on a table in my LinqToSql DataContext object.

Here's the relevant simplified snippet:

```
  public void Update(Customer cust){
    MyDataContext db = new MyDataContext();            
    db.CustomerInvoices.AttachAll(cust.Invoices);  //exception raised here!
    db.Customer.Attach(cust);
  }
```

**Exception raised by the Compiler**:

> The type arguments for method 
>   'System.Data.Linq.Table(**Invoices**).AttachAll(TSubEntity)(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable(TSubEntity))'
>   cannot be inferred from the usage. Try
>   specifying the type arguments
>   explicitly.

**Question**: What is the proper way to cast the collection properly? Any other solutions besides a cast?

Comment: What is cust.Invoices? IEnumerable<Invoice>?

Comment: Thank Zyph. Invoices is of type Invoice as defined in the .dbml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tf cust.Invoices already refers to instances of the CustomerInvoices table, just doing
 db.Customers.Attach(cust); db.Update(); should be all you need to do.

If CustomerInvoices is a different type from Customer.Invoice, you'll probably need to iterate through the collection, and cast each one.

Answer (score 0):

```
public string Save(Role objRole)
{
    string message = string.Empty;
    System.Data.Common.DbTransaction trans = null;    
    try
    {
        Objdb.Connection.Open();
        trans = Objdb.Connection.BeginTransaction();
        Objdb.Transaction = trans; 
        if (objRole.RoleId == 0)
        {
            Objdb.Roles.InsertOnSubmit(objRole);
        }
        else
        {                  
            Objdb.Roles.Attach(objRole, true);
            Objdb.RolePages.AttachAll(objRole.RolePages.Where(a => a.IsNew == false && a.IsDeleted == false), true);
            Objdb.RolePages.InsertAllOnSubmit(objRole.RolePages.Where(a => a.IsNew == true && a.IsDeleted == false));
            Objdb.RolePages.DeleteAllOnSubmit(objRole.RolePages.Where(a => a.IsNew == false && a.IsDeleted == true));
        }
        Objdb.SubmitChanges();
        trans.Commit();  
        message = "Record saved successfully.";
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        trans.Rollback();
        message = "Error : " + ex.Message;
    }
    return message; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        else if (((CheckBox)item.Cells[2].FindControl("ckbSelect")).Checked == true && ((Label)item.Cells[2].FindControl("lblIsInuse")).Text == "1")
        {
            RolePage objTemp = new RolePage();
            objTemp = new Helper().GetRolePagebyID(roleId, Convert.ToInt32(item.Cells[0].Text));
            rp.RoleId = objTemp.RoleId;
            rp.PageId = objTemp.PageId;
            rp.RolePageId = objTemp.RolePageId;
            rp.CreatedOn = objTemp.CreatedOn;
            rp.Timestamp = objTemp.Timestamp; 
            //rp.RoleId = roleId;
            //rp.PageId = Convert.ToInt32(item.Cells[0].Text);
            //rp.RolePageId =Convert.ToInt32(((Label)item.Cells[2].FindControl("lblRolePageId")).Text.Trim());  
            rp.IsNew = false;
            rp.IsDeleted = false;                
            rp.UpdatedOn = DateTime.Now;  
            erp.Add(rp);               
        }
```